# How can I call a method in one file that uses a data structure that has been changed by another file?

Tags: python, file, data-structures, import

I wanted to call a method in one file that picks a random number from a list of numbers with a length defined by another file.

Here's what I currently have:

```
#file1
import file2

class Creator(object):
    def make_shape():
        return Shape(len(file2.sideList)) #takes a parameter of sides

shape = Creator.make_shape() #gets called after sideList is given a certain sequence

#file2
import random

sideList = []

for i in range(1, random.randint(1, 10)):
    sideList.append(i)
```

The obvious problem with the code above is that when file2 is imported, sideList is imported as [] instead of [1, 2, 3, etc]. So when the make_shape() method is called, the shape returned would be a shape with 0 sides.

So how could I "update" sideList in file2 so that I could call the make_shape() method using an "updated" version of file2.sideList?

Comment: drop for loop and just use: `sideList = list(range(1, random.randint(1, 10)))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you create a function in file 2 that accommodates your needs?

```
#file1.py
import file2

class Creator(object):
    def make_shape():
        return Shape(len(file2.sideList())) #takes a parameter of sides

shape = Creator.make_shape() #gets called after sideList is given a certain sequence

#file2.py
import random

def sideList():
    ret = []    
    for i in range(1, random.randint(1, 10)):
        ret.append(i)
    return(ret)
```

Edit:

```
 #file2.py
 import random

 def sideList():
     dataTarget = "__Data__.csv"
     if os.path.isfile(dataTarget):
          fh = open(dataTarget)
          ret = fh.read().split("\n")
     else:
          ret = []    
          for i in range(1, random.randint(1, 10)):
              ret.append(i)
          fh = open(dataTarget)
          fh.write(ret.join(\n))
     fh.close()
     return(ret)
```

Comment: The issue with that is that I specifically need make_shape() to use file2.sideList and not make a new one.

Comment: A bit unfortunate that I have to write data to a txt file, but thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't have to write it to disk it just helps because nothing stays in memory outside of the program executing so you need to save data to the disk for reuse. If you had a third file that needed the same side list as the second file then the third file should import the second and access f2.f1.sidelist, so that it is not regenerated.